# Cohort-style Table (Diagonal Grid) in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join

I need to create a table that is like the image below:
[image]

I can create the full 9 row table in sql using this code:

```
   select a.start_year, a.start_month, b.start_year as order_year, 
          b.start_month as order_month
    from list a
    cross join list b;
```

How can I remove the unwanted rows, or just not create them in the first place?

Comment: It's better to post sample data as text, or even `insert into` statements.

Answer (score 4):

**in ORACLE 11g**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT y, x
  FROM table_name
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX(z)
  FOR x IN (1, 2, 3)
)
ORDER BY y;
```

**in SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT   [y], [1], [2], [3]
FROM   [dbo].[table_name] 
PIVOT
(
       MAX(z)
       FOR [x] IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS P
```

**in PostgreSQL**

First compute the maximum value with the aggregate function [max()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT y, x, MAX(z)
FROM   table_name
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2
```

Then feed the result to the `crosstab()` function as instructed in great detail in this related answer

**Simple form - not fit for missing attributes**

`crosstab()` with *one* parameter:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
      'SELECT x,y, z
       FROM   table_name
       ORDER  BY 1,2')  -- needs to be "ORDER BY 1,2" here
AS ct ("X" text, "1" text, "2" text, "3" text);
```

Returns:

```
   x    |  1  |  2  |  3  
--------+-----+-----+-----
   A    |  a  |  b  |  c  
   B    |  d  |  e  |     
   C    |  f  |     |
```

- No need for casting and renaming.
- Note the **incorrect** result for `C` the value `f` is filled in for the first column.

**Safe form**

`crosstab()` with two parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT x, y, z
        FROM   table_name
        ORDER  BY 1,2'  -- could also just be "ORDER BY 1" here

      ,$$VALUES ('1'::text), ('2'), ('3')$$)
AS ct ("X" text, "1" text, "2" text, "3" text);
```

Returns:

```
   x    |  1  |  2  |  3  
--------+-----+-----+-----
   A    |  a  |  b  |  c  
   B    |  d  |  e  |     
   C    |     |     |  f
```

- Note the correct result for `C`.
- The second parameter can be any query that returns one row per
  attribute matching the order of the column definition at the end.
  Often you will want to query distinct attributes from the underlying
  table like this:

  ```
  'SELECT DISTINCT attribute FROM table_name ORDER BY 1'
  ```

  That's in the manual.

  Since you have to spell out all columns in a column definition list
  anyway (except for pre-defined `crosstabN()` variants), it is regularly
  more efficient to provide a short list in a `VALUES` expression like I
  demonstrate:

  ```
  $$VALUES ('1'::text), ('2'), ('3')$$)
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  $$SELECT unnest('{1,2,3}'::text[])$$ -- shorter for long lists
  ```

  That's not in the manual.

  I used [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to make quoting easier.

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)[postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql)[oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)[sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name for your guidance

Comment: The `values` clause **is** documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name.