# Redshift SQL: How to create a Cohort Triangle (diagonal form) purely in SQL

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table with monthly cohort numbers. It has 3 fields which are cohort, month and user_count. With this table, I want to create another table looking like this ("cohort triangle") purely in SQL if possible:

```
month   2019-07 2019-08 2019-09 2019-10 2019-11
2019-07   200     186     171     160     151
2019-08            81      73      71      69   
2019-09                    46      34      23
2019-10                           100      90 
2019-11                                    80
```

In this schema, the fields are "month", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-10" and "2019-11" (the header line).

Here is a SQL to populate a test cohort table:

```
create table test (
  cohort varchar(7),
  "month" varchar(7),
  user_count int
);
insert into test values
('2019-07', '2019-07', 200),
('2019-07', '2019-08', 186),
('2019-07', '2019-09', 171),
('2019-07', '2019-10', 160),
('2019-07', '2019-11', 151),
('2019-08', '2019-08', 81),
('2019-08', '2019-09', 73),
('2019-08', '2019-10', 71),
('2019-08', '2019-11', 69),
('2019-09', '2019-09', 46),
('2019-09', '2019-10', 34),
('2019-09', '2019-11', 23),
('2019-10', '2019-10', 100),
('2019-10', '2019-11', 90),
('2019-11', '2019-11', 80);
```

Redshift doesn't support CROSSTAB (I checked [Cohort-style Table (Diagonal Grid) in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365078/cohort-style-table-diagonal-grid-in-sql)) so I am having a hard time to convert to the diagonal form.

Comment: its going to be a tough one in redshift. can you do this client side in your bi tool?

Comment: I ended up handling this via Python for now. My use case is to push this to Google Sheet.

Comment: If you are pushing to google sheets, I think you'll find it more flexible to output the query results to a sheet and then pivot on it within google sheets to get the xtab layout